# How do I get my lists to stack on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a calendar out of lists.  I have a list at the top of the page that will go the next/previous month and shows the current month that you are looking at.

```
<ul class="time-selection">
    <li class="calendar-nav">Prev</li>
    <li class="current-month">January 2015</li>
    <li class="calendar-nav">Next</li>
</ul>
```

with the css:

```
.time-selection {
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}
.time-selection li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I then have another list that shows the days of the week.

```
<ul class="days-view">
    <li>
        <span>Sunday</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Monday</span>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

and again the css:

```
.days-view {
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.days-view li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: none!important;
  padding: 10px 6px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

My problem is that my list of days is not appending below the list that controls the months.  I have tried to `clear`, but that is not helping me out.  What do I need to do to get my lists to stack properly?

Comment: At least let me know why you are downvoting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3f968afh/1/

is this what you are looking for?

I adjusted your css to this:

```
  .time-selection {
      width: 33.3% ;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
  }

  .time-selection li {
      float: left;
      width: 33.3% ;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin: 20px 0;
  }

  .days-view {
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      list-style: none;
      clear: both;
  }

  .days-view li {
          float: left;
          text-align: center;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          line-height: 20px;
          border: none!important;
          padding: 10px 6px;
          color: #666;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 5px;
  }
```